# MemoryStream.CopyTo() causing thread to deadlock

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, memorystream

I have an application which, at every tick of a timer, tries to run a backgroundWorker:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!UpdateImageViewerBackgroundWorker.IsBusy)
    {
        UpdateImageViewerBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

When RunWorkerAsync() is called, this function executes:
private void UpdateImageViewerBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender,

```
private void UpdateImageViewerBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var connected = tcp.IsConnected();

    if (connected)
    {
        var stream = tcp.NetworkStream;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            byte[] buffer;

            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();

            ....

        }
    }
    else
    {
        tcp.Connect();
    }
}
```

The problem is that `stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);` causes my backgroundWorker to deadlock, resulting in my `UpdateImageViewerBackgroundWorker.IsBusy` always being `true`.

If I add a breakpoint to the using statement and watch it, as soon as it hits that `stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);`, it steps over and that function is never hit again with the `IsBusy` always `true`...

It works if I define a buffer with a fixed size, and then do `stream.Read(buffer, 0, BYTES_TO_READ);`, but I don't want to define a buffer size as I do not know in advance how large the packet will be.

I have looked around and tried a few methods, including the one in the following post: [Most efficient way of reading data from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542059/most-efficient-way-of-reading-data-from-a-stream) - this does the same...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I can see, you're calling [NetworkStream.CopyTo()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11749522/477878), not MemoryStream.CopyTo()...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, that is correct. NetworkStream has my data -- it is TCPClient.NetworkStream. I want to copy from the networkStream into the memoryStream, just as done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387979/get-length-of-data-available-in-networkstream

Comment: In case the duplicate does not answer your question please reopen. This is the same issue as far as I can tell.

Comment: @usr Thanks, but it seems you are correct. Closing the TCP connectino on the server after each send does indeed fix the problem. However, is that okay - send the data, close the connection and then let the client reconnect?

Comment: @po that's correct but wasteful. Normally, you'd use a framing format such as prepending the message length before the message. Google for that. Better yes, drop TCP and use something higher level such as HTTP or WCF.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need using asynchronic equivalent of this method. Try use stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream); instead of stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);. This will return a Task that can be continued on when completed, like so: await input.CopyToAsync(output).